# setOnItemSelectedListener shuts down the emulator

Tags: android, kotlin, spinner

```
class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity(),AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener {

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)
        var spinnerAdapter=ArrayAdapter.createFromResource(
            this,
            R.array.Şehirler,
            android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item
        )
        spinnerAdapter.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item)

        spnSehirler.setTitle("Şehir Seçin")
        spnSehirler.setPositiveButton("SEÇ")
        spnSehirler.adapter = spinnerAdapter
        spnSehirler.setOnItemSelectedListener(this)
        
        verileriGetir("Tokyo")
    }
    override fun onItemSelected(parent: AdapterView<*>?, view: View?, position: Int, id: Long) {
        var secilenSehir=parent?.getItemAtPosition(position).toString()
        verileriGetir(secilenSehir)
    }
    override fun onNothingSelected(parent: AdapterView<*>?) {
    }
```

setOnItemSelectedListener this code shuts down the emulator. i can't use
The object I selected in the spinner is not set without using it. When I remove this code, the application does not give an error but it cannot work as I want.
How should I do? Can you help me?
[logcat](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kctXe.png)

[image]

The error when adding `spnsehirler.setOnItemSelectedListener` (this) line does not exit without adding

[string array[][3]](https://i.stack.imgur.com/56C39.png)
[[](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IqCMG.png)While the application is open, the items in the array are visible.After activating the code in the comment line, the application quits.[][4][5](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JKQ1W.png)

Comment: show the Logcat and error line

Comment: I added in reply.
sorry. I'm new to this platform

Comment: show the `activity_main` file and `R.array.Şehirler`, it seems that  your array is empty.

Comment: activity_main -Sorry, I am not authorized to add more pictures to the question, line about spinner here I updated the question can you check it?

    <com.toptoche.searchablespinnerlibrary.SearchableSpinner
        android:id="@+id/spnSehirler"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="50dp"
        tools:ignore="MissingConstraints" />

Answer (score 0):

[image: my logcat]

The error when adding spnsehirler.setOnItemSelectedListener (this) line does not exit without adding